# Create Kafka connector but start as paused

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i was looking the way to create a kafka connector but i need it to be created already in paused state.

I already know how to create it, but is always created in running state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - when you create a connector it starts running.